# Is it possible to create an API for SharePoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, api, moss

i could not find any idea of how to implement API over the SharePoint(MOSS) framework.
Could anyone give me a tip please?

What i want to do is create a client application to communicate with the SharePoint.
wanting to implement something like following.

- Client send post request to API implemented on SharePoint, API receive a request and do the authentication and create a login cookie.
- Client keep communicating with API(with the login cookie), request necessary information and API returns it.

I could not find anyway to hook a program...
Is there anyway to hook a program or implement own authentication mechanism before SharePoint's own authentication is called?

Any alternative approach will be grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Taiga

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need the Web Services that ship as part of SharePoint. There is no need to re-invent the wheel by creating your own API.

If your own application runs on a machine with a local SharePoint installation then you can program against the SharePoint Object Model directly. Otherwise use the [Web Services interface](http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services).

[More on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=sharepoint+web+service&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Comment: Thank you for a comment Muhimbi,
I'm not quite sure how to implement against the SharePoint Object Model directly, so ill try start with using Web Services interface.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here you find a fluent API for the SharePoint. FluentSP implements a modern fluent interface around the classic SharePoint 2010 API:
http://www.parago.de/2011/09/fluentsp-the-fluent-sharepoint-api/